# Query regarding multiple arguments in python

Tags: python

I am stuck in a point where i need to support multiple arguments in python.
For example,
if -A, -B, -C are options.
if -A is passed as an argument, it should contain -i option.
if -B is passed as an argument, it should contain -s option.
If -A and -B is passed as an argument, it should contain both -i and -s option.

for example,
it should support following
1.  -A -i 2

2. -B -s 5
3. -A -B -i 2 -s 4
4. -B -A -i 4 -s 5
5. -A -B -s 5 -i 4

Please let me know how to accomplish this.
I was able to acheive 1) and 2).

But, how to implement 3) 4) and 5).

```
parser1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=sys.argv[0])

parser1.add_argument('-A', action='store_true', required=True, help="index option")
parser1.add_argument('-i', type=int, required=True, help="Index value")



parser2 = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=sys.argv[0])

parser2.add_argument('-B', action='store_true', required=True,help="source value option")
parser2.add_argument('-s', type=str, required=True, help="source value")
```

Please help me in getting out of this problem.

Thanks,
Avinash

Comment: Why can't you just do -A 1 or -B 5 pr -A 1 -B 5?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to go back to old parser technique for your solution.
Use `optparse` instead of `argparse`

```
from optparse import OptionParser
usage = "usage: %prog [options] arg"
parser = OptionParser(usage)
parser.add_option("-i", "--index", dest="index",help="Index value")
parser.add_option("-A",action="store_true", dest="A_arg")
[...]
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
if len(args) != 1:
    parser.error("incorrect number of arguments")
if options.A_arg:
    print "A flag not given"
    [...]
[...]
```

just add checks as per your scenario

Answer (score 0):

May be you need subparsers, see below. However the best option would be to try to define your option interface to be like `-A 1 -B 3` etc. Within the code you can assign `1 to i and 3 to s`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse
# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help', dest='subparser_name')

# create the parser for the "A" command
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('A', help='A help')
parser_a.add_argument('i', type=int, help='i help')

# create the parser for the "B" command
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('B', help='B help')
parser_b.add_argument('s', type=int, help='s help')

n = parser.parse_args()
if n.subparser_name == 'A':
    print n.i
elif n.subparser_name == 'B':
    print n.s
else:
    pass # control never reaches here
```

Testing:

```
$ ./argtest.py A 1
1
$ ./argtest.py B 3
3
```

and

```
$ ./argtest.py -h
usage: PROG [-h] {A,B} ...

positional arguments:
  {A,B}       sub-command help
    A         A help
    B         B help

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

and

```
$ ./argtest.py A -h
usage: PROG A [-h] i

positional arguments:
  i           i help

optional arguments:
 -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

and

```
$ ./argtest.py B -h
usage: PROG B [-h] s

positional arguments:
  s           s help

optional arguments:
 -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: Hi abc,
The output of this script is input to some C file. 
That .C file expects the input to be in form like below.
1. -A -i 2

2. -B -s 4

3. -A -B -i 3 -s 3

I jus need to parse to verify its in correct format.

Comment: @user1385290 Please describe what you are actually trying to accomplish in detail. May be this is an opportunity for you to re-think your design.